# I'm creating this Roblox game but I don't want the user to have multiple of the same items

Tags: lua, scripting, game-development, roblox

I'm creating a shop for my game and I don't want the user to be able to buy the same item multiple times my script works fine when the item isn't equipped but when it is I'm able to buy another one.

This is my current script

```lua
local function buy (plr)
    local leaderstats = plr:FindFirstChild('leaderstats')
    if leaderstats then
        local coins = leaderstats:FindFirstChild('Murabux')
        if not plr:WaitForChild("Backpack"):FindFirstChild("Katana") then
            if coins and coins.Value >= 90 then
                coins.Value = coins.Value - 90
                local clone = game:GetService('ReplicatedStorage').Katana:Clone()
                clone.Parent = plr.Backpack
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: take a look at https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Tool and verify the equipped Tools too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is lacking a check for the held item from the player, which is under their character.

Correction:

```
local function buy (plr)
    local leaderstats = plr:FindFirstChild('leaderstats')
    if leaderstats then
        local coins = leaderstats:FindFirstChild('Murabux')
        if not plr:WaitForChild("Backpack"):FindFirstChild("Katana") and not plr.Character:FindFirstChild("Katana") then
            if coins and coins.Value >= 90 then
                coins.Value = coins.Value - 90
                local clone = game:GetService('ReplicatedStorage').Katana:Clone()
                clone.Parent = plr.Backpack
            end
        end
    end
end
```